# React svg image

Tags: reactjs, svg, graphical-logo

I know nothing about React, but I was entrust to do a little task, simple at glance, but Im not been able to complete.
I been manipulating a code that I think create an svg a icon in a webpage, this is the code:

```
            var EuiIconLogoKibana = function EuiIconLogoKibana(props) {
                return _react.default.createElement("svg", _extends({
                    width: 32,
                    height: 32,
                    viewBox: "0 0 32 32",
                    xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                }, props), _react.default.createElement("g", {
                    fill: "none",
                    fillRule: "evenodd"
                }, _react.default.createElement("path", {
                    fill: "#F04E98",
                    d: "M4 0v28.789L28.935.017z"
                }), _react.default.createElement("path", {
                    fill: "#00BFB3",
                    d: "M18.479 16.664L6.268 30.754l-1.073 1.237h23.191c-1.252-6.292-4.883-11.719-9.908-15.327"
                })))
            };
```

I have to change that Icon, so I have a png image, I converted that png to svg with https://convertio.co/, I opened with vs code and get this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="758.000000pt" height="758.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 758.000000 758.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

<g transform="translate(0.000000,758.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M3570 6184 c-265 ...TOO MANY NUMBERS"/>
<path d="M3595 3162 c-106 ...TOO MANY NUMBERS"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

So I thougt that copying the path of the SVG into the the path of the "_react.default.createElement" will draw the image that I want but, I cant get it to work...any ideas of what can I do to solve this?

Comment: If you know nothing about React, we have no reason to fix your code: you're just not going to know why it works. Instead, I can heartily recommend deleting this question and then taking the take to run through the official React tutorial over on https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html, which is both well written, and comprehensive. Especially if this is part of your job (paid or unpaid), take the hour to learn the basics of React, because it's not hard, but you _do_ need to follow the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"M" on a SVG Path means "move to", so I was in the right track, but the image I was trying to draw was to big to fit the space, I started drawing in the 3570 pixel, but the size was determined by:

```
_react.default.createElement("svg", _extends({
                    width: 32,
                    height: 32,
                    viewBox: "0 0 32 32",
```

I just have to resize the drawing and It works.

Maybe this will be useful for somebody, learnin or working, I dont care, I share.
don't be like "BBQ" Becky, "Permit" Patty, "Cornerstore" Caroline or Mike "Over-React"